# Is it possible to get the label of the next frame in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Had a look for this but nothing seemed clear at the moment I have a script which will only play if the frame is the currentFrameLabel or rewind.

However in order for it not to go one frame too far I need to be able to stop it on the frame before the change not on the change.

Or am I just going about this the wrong way?

For example:

Frame 10 Label: Up
Frame 12-36 Label: Idle Loop
Frame 37 Label: Hand Up

I need it to only play from frames 12 to 36 but at the moment it plays from frames 12-37.

```
var reverse:Boolean = false;
var robotlabel:String = 'Up/Down';

what.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, botAction);
what.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, botAction2);

function botAction(evt:MouseEvent):void{
reverse = false;
robotlabel = 'Hand up/Down';
robot.gotoAndPlay('Hand up/Down');
robot.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,run);
}

function botAction2(evt:MouseEvent):void{
reverse = true;
robot.prevFrame();
}

function run(e:Event):void{

trace("label:" + robotlabel);
trace("current" + robot.currentFrameLabel);

if(robot.currentFrameLabel != robotlabel && robot.currentFrameLabel != null){
    trace("stoooooppppp");
    robot.stop();
}

    if(reverse == true && currentFrameLabel==robotlabel){
        robot.prevFrame();
    trace("reversing!");
    }else if(reverse == false && (currentFrameLabel==robotlabel || robot.currentFrameLabel == null)){
    robot.nextFrame();
}else{
    trace("destroy");
    reverse = false;
    robot.stop();
    robot.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,run);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a "nextFrameLabel" property as such in as3, however you can get an array of all the frame labels and numbers in your target movieclip using the [currentLabel property of the MovieClip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentLabel) and work it out from there, since you know the currentFrame at all times.

Quick example from the docs:

```
import flash.display.FrameLabel;

var labels:Array = mc1.currentLabels;

for (var i:uint = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
{
    var label:FrameLabel = labels[i];
    trace("frame " + label.frame + ": " + label.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful to anybody else I solved it by looping through each frame and then storing the corresponding label to the frame so it can later be checked against.

```
for (i = 1; i < robot.totalFrames; i++)
{

for (var n:uint = 0; n < this.robolabels.length; n++)
{

    if(this.robolabels[n].frame == i){
        newLabel = this.robolabels[n].name
    }

}

this.roboframes[i] = newLabel;
}
```